# Create another column in csv file but getting Error csv file is closed

Tags: python-3.x

I've taken a csv dataset and created an output csv with a new column to calculate lat/long coordinates by distance in km. At the end of my loop I wanted to create another column for distance in meters, but I keep getting an error that the csv file is closed. How can I nest this within my current if/else loop or reopen the csv and add a new column?

```py
lat = float(row[latIndex])
lon = float(row[lonIndex]) 
if latPrev == -9999: #if statement for previous lat
    latPrev = lat #resets lat
    lonPrev = lon #resets lon
    continue 
else: 
    #Distance formula for KM
else:
    kilometer = float("DistanceKM")
    meter = kilometer*1000
    row.append(meter)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You can reopen it like you opened it before.

Comment: @mkrieger1 that is true, but generally, using `with open` is safer. Furthermore, this piece of code intended to looping and input to csv file.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni yes, that's a good idea. I didn't mean to say not to use `with`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `with open` to savely open and close file. There is many SO QnA about `with open`, but I can't find a good one to mark this question as duplicate.

For now, this is the answer:

```py
with open('FILENAME.csv', 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # your loop here
    for latIndex, lonIndex  in zip(lats, lons):
        lat = float(row[latIndex])
        lon = float(row[lonIndex])
        if latPrev == -9999: #if statement for previous lat
            latPrev = lat #resets lat
            lonPrev = lon #resets lon
            continue 
        else: 
            #Distance formula for KM
        else:
            kilometer = float("DistanceKM")
            meter = kilometer*1000
            row.append(meter)
            f.writerow(row)
```